# PostgreSQL 9.2 number of days in a tstzrange?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgresql-9.2

How can the number of days contained within a range be found?

For example, with these timestamp ranges, get these (integer) number of days:

```
tstzrange('2013-10-01 07:00', '2013-10-01 07:15') | 1 (day)
tstzrange('2013-10-01 07:00', '2013-10-01 23:45') | 1 (day)
tstzrange('2013-10-01 02:00', '2013-10-02 23:45') | 2 (days)
tstzrange('2013-10-01 07:00', '2013-10-03 01:00') | 2 (days)
tstzrange('2013-10-01 01:00', '2013-10-03 23:00') | 3 (days)
tstzrange('2013-10-01 23:00', '2013-10-04 01:00') | 4 (days)
```

In my digging about, I've not found a built in function for this.

Is is necessary pull out the `lower()` and `upper()` timestamp elements, then get the date interval between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do this, but here are a few functions to return days or intervals from a tstzrange/tsrange input parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_interval(TSTZRANGE) RETURNS interval AS
$func$
select upper($1) - lower($1);
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_interval(TSRANGE) RETURNS interval AS
$func$
select upper($1) - lower($1);
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_days(TSTZRANGE) RETURNS integer AS
$func$
select (date_trunc('day',upper($1))::DATE - date_trunc('day',lower($1))::DATE) + 1;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_days(TSRANGE) RETURNS integer AS
$func$
select (date_trunc('day',upper($1))::DATE - date_trunc('day',lower($1))::DATE) + 1;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;


WITH tzr AS (SELECT tstzrange('2013-10-01 10:00-07', '2013-10-03 05:15-07') AS dttz, tstzrange('2013-10-01 10:00', '2013-10-03 05:15') AS dt)
SELECT  extract_interval(dttz) as interval_with_tz,
        extract_interval(dt) as interval_no_tz,
        extract_days(dttz) as days_with_tz,
        extract_days(dt) as days_no_tz
FROM tzr;

                      tstzrange                      | interval_with_tz | interval_no_tz | days_with_tz | days_no_tz 
-----------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------
 ["2013-10-01 07:00:00-07","2013-10-01 07:15:00-07") | 00:15:00         | 00:15:00       |            1 |          1
```

Edit: I have put up these functions on the Postgresql Wiki so that others can use or edit them if more efficient versions are developed.
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Extract_days_from_range_type

Comment: NOTE: Those functions don't exactly return the correct data in the case where the bounds are exclusive. In the given example, 07:15 is NOT actually in the given range.